# Reachability issues since updating to iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, reachability

I have a tried and tested enterprise iPhone app that's been in heavy use for over a year, and works great.  The app makes frequent use of asynchronous NSURLConnectionRequests to fetch data from  a server.

I monitor availability of network connectivity using Apple's 'Reachability' sample code.  I've always considered the Reachability code to be a bit fragile, but I've had it working solidly for many months - iOS 4.3 onwards.

However, I'm now seeing a problem since upgrading to iOS 6.  Seemingly randomly, after a day or two of dipping in and out of the app, I open the app and notice (via the console) that the app is receiving repeated 'network available' notifications from the Reachability class.

If I stop the task (and I mean, properly stop), and relaunch, the problem goes away, and the app behaves normally again.

Of course, this could be down to a subtle issue with my integration of the Reachability code (I've mentioned that I consider it 'fragile'), but I'm wondering if anyone has seen something similar since updating to iOS 6?

I did have a play with the iOS 6 -> Settings -> Developer Settings -> Network Link Conditioner, and it certainly feels like this problem has appeared since then, but it's definitely now turned off, and I've rebooted the device.

Anyone else seeing Reachability issues since updating to iOS 6?

Comment: After these occurrences, I haven't seen this problem again, which makes me think it was a side effect of the Network Link Conditioner.  However, this question seems to be getting some interest on SO, so if you've seen this problem yourself (specifically since the iOS 6 update), please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to assume this problem, that I saw twice, has magically 'gone away'.

If anyone else also sees it, please add to comments.